# ConsoleTools with unnamed arguments

Tags: c#, command-line, console-application, command-line-arguments, command-line-parser

## Description

I´ve got a console application which has a lot of arguments. To manage them I use the nuget package [commandlineparser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline). It works really nice but one argument dosen´t have a option like -r or --reload. Did anyone get a idea how to catch a unnamed argument?

Example arguments: `-p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro --restart always --log-opt max-size=1g nginx`

## Program.cs

```
using DockerComposeConverterTool.Commands;
using DustInTheWind.ConsoleTools;
using DustInTheWind.ConsoleTools.Menues;
using DustInTheWind.ConsoleTools.InputControls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CommandLine;

namespace DockerComposeConverterTool
{
    class Program
    {
        public static StringListView Services = new StringListView();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                PrintMenu();
            }
            else
            {
                var parser = new Parser(options =>
                {
                    options.IgnoreUnknownArguments = false;
                    options.CaseSensitive = false;
                });
                var result = parser.ParseArguments<ArgumentOptions>(args)
                    .WithNotParsed<ArgumentOptions>(o =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(o);
                    })
                   .WithParsed<ArgumentOptions>(o =>
                   {
                       if (o.Verbose)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine($"Verbose output enabled. Current Arguments: -v {o.Verbose}");
                           Console.WriteLine("Quick Start Example! App is in Verbose mode!");
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine($"Current Arguments: -v {o.Verbose}");
                           Console.WriteLine("Quick Start Example!");
                       }
                   });
                var parsedValue = ((Parsed<ArgumentOptions>)result).Value;
                Console.WriteLine();
                //foreach(var arg in args)
                //{
                //    Console.WriteLine(arg);
                //}
            }

            Environment.Exit(0);

            //var test = new Converter(new List<DockerComposeServiceModel>(new DockerComposeServiceModel
            //{
            //    Service = "Testvalue",
            //    Parameters = new DockerComposeConverterCore.Parameters.DockerParameter()
            //}));
            //Console.WriteLine(test.GetYamlComposeModel());


            //CustomConsole.WriteLine("Normal: This is a normal line of text.");
            //CustomConsole.WriteLine();
            //CustomConsole.WriteLineEmphasies("Emphasies: But I can also write an emphasized text.");
            //CustomConsole.WriteLine();
            //CustomConsole.WriteLineSuccess("Success: And everything is ok if it finishes well :)");
            //CustomConsole.WriteLine();
            //CustomConsole.WriteLineWarning("Warning: But I have to warn you about the consequences of something not being done correctly.");
            //CustomConsole.WriteLine();
            //CustomConsole.WriteLineError("Error: If some error occures and the application will crush with an exception, I will display it on the screen immediately.");
        }

        static void PrintMenu()
        {
            Console.Clear();

            HorizontalLine.QuickDisplay();
            CustomConsole.WriteLineEmphasies(@"[$$$$$$$$\ $$\                       $$\            $$$$$$\                  $$\]");
            CustomConsole.WriteLineEmphasies(@"[$$  _____|\__|                      $$ |          $$  __$$\                 $$ |]");
            CustomConsole.WriteLineEmphasies(@"[$$ |      $$\  $$$$$$\   $$$$$$$\ $$$$$$\         $$ /  \__| $$$$$$\   $$$$$$$ | $$$$$$\   $$$$$$\]");
            CustomConsole.WriteLineEmphasies(@"[$$$$$\    $$ |$$  __$$\ $$  _____|\_$$  _|$$$$$$\ $$ |      $$  __$$\ $$  __$$ |$$  __$$\ $$  __$$\]");
            CustomConsole.WriteLineEmphasies(@"[$$  __|   $$ |$$ |  \__|\$$$$$$\    $$ |  \______|$$ |      $$ /  $$ |$$ /  $$ |$$$$$$$$ |$$ |  \__|]");
            CustomConsole.WriteLineEmphasies(@"[$$ |      $$ |$$ |       \____$$\   $$ |$$\       $$ |  $$\ $$ |  $$ |$$ |  $$ |$$   ____|$$ |]");
            CustomConsole.WriteLineEmphasies(@"[$$ |      $$ |$$ |      $$$$$$$  |  \$$$$  |      \$$$$$$  |\$$$$$$  |\$$$$$$$ |\$$$$$$$\ $$ |]");
            CustomConsole.WriteLineEmphasies(@"[\__|      \__|\__|      \_______/    \____/        \______/  \______/  \_______| \_______|\__|]");
            HorizontalLine.QuickDisplay();
            if (Services.Values != null && !Services.Values.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                Services.Write();
                HorizontalLine.QuickDisplay();
            }

            TextMenu textMenu = new TextMenu
            {
                TitleText = "Docker Compose Converter Tool",
                TitleForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan,
                EraseAfterClose = false
            };

            textMenu.AddItems(new List<TextMenuItem>
            {
                new TextMenuItem
                {
                    Id = "1",
                    Text = "Add Service"
                },
                new TextMenuItem
                {
                    Id = "2",
                    Text = "Remove Service"
                },
                new TextMenuItem
                {
                    Id = "3",
                    Text = "Clear Services"
                },
                new TextMenuItem
                {
                    Id = "4",
                    Text = "Print Service to console"
                },
                new TextMenuItem
                {
                    Id = "4",
                    Text = "Print Service docker-compose.yml"
                },
                new TextMenuItem
                {
                    Id = "0",
                    Text = "Exit",
                    Command = new ExitCommand()
                }
            });

            textMenu.Display();
            PrintMenu();
        }
    }
}
```

## Picture of the parsedValue

[image]

Comment: In [docs](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline#quick-start-examples), you can find an example with the custom options you want.

Comment: Yes. I know. But I didn´t found a example without a parameter like -x or --x

Comment: `[Option('x', "xoption" , Required = false ...` i think that is